# YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI inside Collapsing Toolbar Layout

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I try to implement YouTube player inside CollapsingToolbarLayout. And I faced with problem that video stopped every second with log message

> W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.olearis.drake1804.muzeek.presentation.view.screen.genre.GenreDetailsActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtubeFrameContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0D4C5C"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/youtubePreview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/tint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#4D000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleVideo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/youtubeStart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="24dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_genre_details" />
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @AbhishekV nope

Answer (score 0):

Add the title inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and hide it when the video starts playing.